# SuiteScript 2.0 search.Type is undefined

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

I am trying something like below:

```
require(['N/search'],
    function(search)
    {
            var mySearch = search.create({
                type : search.Type.FOLDER,
                columns : ['internalid'],
                filters : [ 'internalid', 'anyof', ID]
            });
            mySearch.run();
    });
```

I get an error for `search.Type.FOLDER` that `search.Type` is `undefined` and so cannot find `FOLDER` of `undefined`

I was able to do a workaround by writing a type as `'folder'` that worked, but, why is this enum not defined if it is documented in NetSuite's help.

I tried even logging all keys using `Object.keys` and the returned array does not contains `Type` key.

Has anyone tried this or if anyone can point out if something is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see anything wrong with your code, and I confirmed in my own instance that the module brought in by `N/search` *does not* include a `Type` enum. Including the `N/record` module *does* have correctly have the `Type` enum, so if you want to avoid the magic string `'folder'`, you could import `N/record` and use `record.Type.FOLDER` instead.

It's not ideal, as what you are doing *should* work, but it seems there must be a bug in the search module where they're not properly returning the Type enum.

Comment: yeah I have already tried `record.Type.FOLDER` and did worked. Since, it is in your instance as well it looks like a genuine bug from NetSuite. Anyways it is in beta